# How to use big-cursor in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, cursor

I've installed the big-cursor package in Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, but it doesn't show up on the update-alternatives list, and I can't find any instructions on how to use it.

I use the dwm window manager and the command line (i.e., no Gnome, etc.). How do I use the cursor theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cursor themes are configured via [environment variables](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xcursor/xcursor.html#h2-ENVIRONMENT-VARIABLES) (or X resource settings of the ***Xcursor*** library).